# Symfony configuration problems - not recognizing symfony as an command

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a problem with symfony configuration. I installed symfony and configure everything as in tutorials, but i can't start server in my project file, because i've got that kind of error :

**'symfony' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I tried to reinstall whole packet and I'm still geting same result. What I need to reconfigure or change?

Comment: What is your OS? Where did you install the Symfony CLI and how?

Answer (score 0):

You must install the Symfony CLI (the `symfony` binary) separately from the libraries/bundles/packages.

See the [Symfony CLI installation instructions](https://symfony.com/download#step-1-install-symfony-cli) for more information.

This is typically done *first*, so your answer makes it unclear how you may have "installed symfony". If you indeed installed the CLI, you may have to take additional steps to make it globally available depending on your platform.

Comment: Yes, I already installed Symfony CLI and it's not still available. What kind of steps i need to take to make it globallu available on windows 10?

Comment: Edit. I uninstalled sympfony and installed it from Scoop